# Comparision of norms

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G^s(\Omega), s>1$ be the Gevrey space which is the subset of $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. The norm on $C^{\infty}$ is the usual sup norm on compact subset. And the norm on $G^s$ is defined as

$||u||=\sup \sup C^{-|\alpha|-1}(\alpha !)^{-s}|D^\alpha u(x)|$, where the supremum is taken all over multi indices $\alpha$ ana all $x$ in a compact set. What I want to know is that whether there are cases in which convergence in $C^\infty$ implies convergence in $G^s$. I know the converse holds as $G^s\subset C^\infty$ .